# Откуда взялась черная рамка?

Tags: css

Заметил странные изменения в CSS, наверное это хром так обновился. Я незнаток.

Раньше селект открывался красиво, а теперь как-то криво. Не могу понять как задать `padding`, `margin` и прочее, потому как при любом клике селект сворачивается.
Как убрать черную рамку ну и все остальное?

```
outline: 0;
border: none;
```

не помогает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Стилизовать option'ы в общем случае почти невозможно, на каждой платформе они отображаются по-своему

Answer (score 1):

С выпуском Chrome M83 они сделали это фишкой "акцента внимания".

Пока нет фиксов, а :focus-visible, :focus и :hover не работают для option в этой версии хрома

Тоже раздражает, но решения пока не нашел :)

[вот тут описывают нововведения](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/03/updates-to-form-controls-and-focus.html)